# How to query the first entry in each group in NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

The following code using LINQ in NHibernate returns a different result from in-memory LINQ and EF LINQ. What is the correct way to do this in NHibernate? It is fine to use `QueryOver` if the LINQ version is indeed broken.

```
using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        session.Save(new A()
        {
            X = i % 2,
            Y = i / 2,
        });
    }
    transaction.Commit();
}
using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    //=====================================
    var expected = session.Query<A>()
        .ToList() // <-- copy to memory
        .GroupBy(a => a.X)
        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(y => y.Y).First())
        .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", expected.Select(a => a.Id)));
    //=====================================
    var actual = session.Query<A>()
        .GroupBy(a => a.X)
        .Select(g => g.OrderBy(y => y.Y).First())
        .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", actual.Select(a => a.Id)));
}

public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; } // indexed
    public int Y { get; set; } // indexed
}
```

Expected results

```
1 2
```

Actual results

```
1 1
```

Logged SQL

```
NHibernate: select (select program_a0_.Id as id1_0_ from "A" program_a0_ order by program_a0_.Y asc limit 1) as col_0_0_ from "A" program_a0_ group by program_a0_.X
```

The full code is in the bug report [Incorrect result when using GroupBy with First](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/2168)

---

Update 2019-8-9

The query should not use ID. I have changed it to a non-unique property. I would appreciate if the solution only query once to SQLite.

Comment: have you tried replicating the issue without NHibernate?

Comment: Yes, I discovered this problem when changing the code to use NH from EF. The in-memory version and EF gave the same result. NH gave a different result. I reduced the code to the above version.

Comment: Could you provide what SQL query generate NHibernate?

Comment: My SQL statement skill is very rusty. Giving one will probably redirect the solution to something weird. It seems that the solution should be something like `select * from A ??? join (select ??? from A groupby X ???)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems latest NHibernate 5.3 LINQ provider supports only aggregate functions (MIN, MAX, COUNT...) in Select for "group by" query. Entity select is not supported in group by queries.

As a general solution you can rewrite your "group by" query with subquery using the following approach:

```
var results = session.Query<A>()
     .Where(a => a == session.Query<A>() // Subquery on same entity
                         .Where(sa => sa.X == a.X) // Group BY key is here
                         .OrderBy(sa => sa.Y) // Order By key is here
                         .First() // First entry in group
     ).ToList();
```

Original "group by" query for reference:

```
var results = session.Query<A>()
    .GroupBy(a => a.X)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(y => y.Y).First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a join version? I get a NotSupported exception using LINQ. It seems that I have to use QueryOver but I still have no ideas after searching on the Internet.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "join version". But afaik joins on subquery are not supported in NHibernate LINQ/QueryOver.